# Best Practices for Encryption

Tags: mongodb, security, encryption

I have some sensitive information in a MongoDB collection which needs to be encrypted and decrypted. Only one section needs to be encrypted, so I could use the other values as a form of entropy. I have two ideas:

- Generate a pseudorandom key from the other keys in the document, and have each document use a different key
- Use one key for all the databases

I feel like the former would be more secure, but what would be a good way of making the pseudorandom generator?

If the first is a poor idea, what would be the best way to store the key for the databases?

Comment: The problem with the first solution you have is that you would have to store the key to decrypt in the document and that wouldn't be much of a challenge if your db get compromised, this might be better off on one of the computer security stack exchanges instead

Comment: No, say they have an id, email, etc. Use that information to form a key.

Comment: It will still be too obvious, honestly any data in the document used as the key will be too obvious, even in combination

Comment: Even if I took the username, hashed it n times, email, hashed it m times, added a fixed string, then hashed it l times? Etc.

Comment: If the key can be generated from just data that is publicly accessible then it is too obvious. You would be talking obfuscation instead of encryption. How to store a key opens the can of worms that is called key management. You can write books about that. A common method is storing an external key on a removable drive, or use a key derivation function on a password (PBKDF2).

Comment: and if your db is stolen then even private data is a gonner

Comment: The problem with hashing is then how will you know the sum of the hash the next time without storing it? no matter where you go you still have to store enough data to make it easy

Comment: Owlstead is correct, I was on about obfuscation. To keep me amused, say I had a key and used it as the fixed string mentioned earlier, would that be any more secure than just using the key everywhere? And Sammaye, I would just generate it each time—the hash was just to generate a pseudorandom key.

Comment: The problem is that key has gotta be a cipher for your encryption, a hash will randomise the representation of its sum each time it is run as such the cipher key will never be correct after the first encryption which leaves you with unreadable data.

Comment: No, sorry. The format is { username, email, data }. Only data is encrypted, so the username and email can be used at any point to generate the key.

Comment: Wait backup, wernt you saying you was going to use a hash of those to formulate the key though? And the key is the cipher to unlock as such the key is partly made of the hash of the information in those fields isn't it? The problem with obfuscation is the same problem you get with stored passwords, they cannot be reversed, not without great pain

Comment: Yes, the key is partly made from repeated hashes the fields. It is also made up of an actual key. A key for a document would be generated on the fly, and that key would be used to decrypt the data. Am I way overthinking this, and is a key without this obfuscation just fine?

Comment: You are way over thinking this, a key needs to always be the same constant value in order to get your data back, the way you are thinking of it atm will create a variable key that will not be able to decrypt without storing a static hash of the fields in the document. But at the same time no, a key without this is not fine, when you loose your database (lets face it with any database; when) it will be hacked faster than md5

Comment: Though I have been sooooo stupid of course it won't create a variable key

Comment: I still think you are misunderstanding. The username and email are not encrypted. They are stored as plaintext. I can hash them on the fly to generate part of a final key. The final key will consist of the hashes to the username and password and another random key. That way, if they get the key, they have to figure out how to use it. Still overthinking?

Comment: No it should be OK, I was considering that the hash of the plain text fields will always be different but they won't be. Must have been confused with something else. Though where does that random key come from, remember that you gotta provide the exact same key as you used to encrypt

Comment: Yea, I will need a final key. I just figured it is probably safer to have extra measures in place. Just don't want to do a Sony. ;)

Comment: Indeed don't want to go down that route, I would also post this on the computer security exchange and see what they say, they might have a good idea on how to keep that last key